# How does it know what the second arg in __init__ is? I don't call it out anywhere but it works

Tags: python

I'm getting a bit confused here, I'm making the alien game from pygame tutorial.

I've been making the bullets and I don't understand. In the bullet's `__init__`, it calls ai_game as the second arg, but how does it know to reference the `AlienInvasion` class?  I don't create a variable anywhere called ai_game.  and I don't have to say `ai_game = AlienInvasion` in the `__init__`.

```
class Bullet(Sprite):
"""A class to manage bullets fired from the ship"""

def __init__(self, ai_game):
    """Create a bullet object at the ship's current position."""
    super().__init__()
    self.screen = ai_game.screen
    self.settings = ai_game.settings
    self.color=self.settings.bullet_color

    # Create a bullet rect at (0, 0) and then set correct position.
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0,0, self.settings.bullet_width, self.settings.bullet_height)
    self.rect.midtop = ai_game.ship.rect.midtop

    # Store the bullet's position as a decimal value.
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)


class AlienInvasion:
"""Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

def __init__(self):
    """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
    pygame.init()
    self.settings = Settings()

    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    self.ship = Ship(self)

    #set the background color.
    self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)


def run_game(self):
    """Start the main loop for the game."""
    while True:
        self._check_events()
        self._update_screen()
        self.ship.update()
        # redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
```

Comment: But you haven't created any Bullets at all in this example?

Comment: You are creating the variable named `ai_game` right there, as argument: `__init__ (self, ai_game)`. And you are probably going to pass the `AlienInvasion` instance into it later when you instatiate a bullet with `Bullet(self)`. If this code is inside of the `AlienInvasion` class, the `self` will be the instance and become the second argument to `Bullet`'s `__init__`, `ai_game` (the first argument will always be the new bullet itself, then also called `self`).

Comment: @cherryDT ohhhh ok i think i get it now, thank you!  yes I do call it in the AlienInvasion class, so it just automatically fills it out there.  Gotcha gotcha.